# Missing @inject annotation, which isn't missing in inversify with an extending class

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, inversifyjs

I'm having a problem which seems a bit hard to put into a title, which is why you've gotten this beast of a title.

I get an error stating: `Error: Missing required @inject or @multiInject annotation in: argument 0 in class SceneRepository.`.
This seems simple enough, I should add an `@inject` annotation to my first argument. This is my constructor though:

```
export class SceneRepository extends BaseRepository<IScene> {
  constructor(@inject(SceneSchema) private sceneSchema: SceneSchema) {
    super(sceneSchema.schema);
  }
}
```

And for the sake of being complete, this is what my BaseRepository looks like:

```
export class BaseRepository<T extends Document> implements IWrite<T>, IRead<T>{
  constructor(private _model: Model<Document>) {

  }
  ...
}
```

`Model<Document>` Comes from a third party library (mongoose).

I have no clue to what I'm doing wrong here, so if you could nudge me in the correct direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi @andrew, no I haven't, **and** yes I have. I did some rewriting and wrote around the error. You'll forgive me for not remembering the specifics? But IIRC i simply created a getter and a setter for the `_model`, and no longer set it using `super()`. Because I believe it had to do with having required completely different parameters to the constructor. So I did not really fix the issue, I removed it :D

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and in my case, instead of constructor injection, I used property injection to get away with this error and also got the injection working.

```
export class SceneRepository extends BaseRepository<IScene> {
    @inject(SceneSchema)
    private sceneSchema: SceneSchema;
    constructor() {
        super(this.sceneSchema.schema);
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `'TypescriptInterface' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here` I got this error if I add `@inject(TypescriptInterface)`